Override properties of an interface dynamically in TypeScript
Is there a way I can wrap each property in an interface with a generic type dynamically?
I have multiple interfaces that are defined in a library. I cannot modify it (i.e., add generics, for example). The following interface is an example of one of the possible interfaces I have that is defined in a library.
interface Original {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

I also have this generic type that I use for displaying the values in the interface. (I.e., each interface attribute will have its own svg icon, units, etc...) I have made this generic myself.
interface GenericInterface<V> {
    value: V;
    units: string;
    errorMsg?: string;
    icons: ReactElement<any>;
}

What I want to do is wrap each parameter in the Original interface with the GenericInterface. Resulting in the following:
interface Modified {
    a: GenericInterface<string>;
    b: GenericInterface<number>;
    c: GenericInterface<boolean>;
}

The closest I have come to achieving this is the following:
type ModifiedGeneric<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = Record<
    K,
    GenericInterface<T[K]>
>;

type Modified = ModifiedGeneric<
    Original,
    keyof Original
>;

But this results in a union of the all interface parameters types. i.e.,
interface Modified {
    a: GenericInterface<string | number | boolean>;
    b: GenericInterface<string | number | boolean>;
    c: GenericInterface<string | number | boolean>;
}

Does anyone known of a solution that I can use to achieve the desired output?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html?

As jonrsharpe suggests in the comments, just use a mapped type:
interface Original {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

interface GenericInterface<V> {
    value: V;
    units: string;
    errorMsg?: string;
    icons: React.ReactElement<any>;
}

type ModifiedGeneric<T extends {}> = {
    [key in keyof T]: GenericInterface<T[key]>
}

type ModifiedOriginal = ModifiedGeneric<Original>
// ModifiedOriginal has type
// {
//   a: GenericInterface<string>;
//   b: GenericInterface<number>;
//   c: GenericInterface<boolean>;
// }

Playground
Note that the second generic param isn't needed, unless you want to be able to do this with a subset of keyof T.
